# matplotlib.imshow(): why is img color distorted?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

The original image of `mandrill.jpg` looks like this:

[image]

Why and how does `imshow()` change it this way?

[image]

Comment: It depends on colormap. Matlab 2014b and higher versions use parula colormap; earlier versions use jet colormap. Windows have a differenet one . So the color will change in different colormaps.

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: The most recent one, but I more am curious as to what the purpose of this color change is.

Comment: For Imaging, we use different colormaps in different imaging method for better visualization of suspicious regions.

Comment: It looks as though the order of the color channels in the image are reversed, i.e. the image is stored as BGR, but is being displayed as RGB. Try `plt.imshow(image[..., ::-1])` to reverse the last dimension of the array.